# More Efficient SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Okay I'm doing a data conversion. I've got 12 or so columns in my new database table where I need to find only the most recent transaction for each product in the old database. Twelve times in my query I need a single value from a massive table of transactions.

To get the latest transaction I'm using a nested Inner Join to find the 'max'. These nested querys are killing the efficiency and the subtables are huge. My query is taking about 20 seconds when pulling just a sample of 100 products. I've got ~10,000. Any suggestions to make my nested queries more efficient? Here is an example of one of these nested Inner Joins.

```
   LEFT JOIN coverage_schedule CS_PL
     ON R.risk_pk = CS_PL.risk_fk
        AND CS_PL.coverage_type = 'HOMCVGE'
   LEFT JOIN ( Coverage_tran CT_PL
               JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(pct.coverage_tran_pk) AS recent,
                                     pct.coverage_schedule_fk,
                                     pcs.coverage_type
                     FROM   Coverage_tran pct
                            LEFT JOIN TRANSACTION pt
                              ON pct.transaction_fk = pt.transaction_pk
                            LEFT JOIN coverage_schedule pcs
                              ON pct.coverage_schedule_fk =
                                 pcs.po_coverage_schedule_pk
                                 AND pcs.coverage_type = 'HOMCVGE'
                     WHERE  pt.transaction_cycle = 'issued'
                            AND pct.cvg_status = 'Active'
                     GROUP  BY pct.coverage_schedule_fk,
                               pcs.coverage_type,
                               pt.transaction_cycle) mCT2
                 ON CT_PL.coverage_schedule_fk = mCT2.coverage_schedule_fk
                    AND CT_PL.coverage_tran_pk = mCT2.recent )
     ON CS_PL.coverage_schedule_pk = CT_PL.coverage_schedule_fk
        AND CT_PL.cvg_status = 'Active'
```

I've tried restricting the nested table query to just transactions of the correct 'coverage type' in this sample the coverage is called 'HOMCVGE' I've also restricted to just products with 'Active' status. I also tried removing the 'coverage' column from the table as I don't need it as both a column and as a restriction/rule for the join. I assumed restricting sample size would make it more efficient but I see no noticeable effect. Do I just need to shrink the table size by adding more restrictions? Is it better to place the restrictions in the 'join' or in the 'where' clause?

The Execution Plan is showing the nested query above has a cost of 11.6911 / 8% It's about the most expensive thing in the whole query... but that just tells me its slowing it down and I already knew that.

Any hints, clues, or tools I can use?  I admit I've taken no classes on SQL so I haven't been taught any best practices and don't know the Big O costs. Heck I just found the Execution Plan 10 minutes ago.

Update-------------------
I was able to shave off several seconds by removing unnecessary columns and groupings. So thank you. I hope I can make it even more efficient. I also found that when possible, it is better to add a restriction to the query in the 'where' clause and not attached directly to the 'JOIN' clause.

X-Zero, the way I see it I have two options. Basically I am looking for the current features on a product. In the new database I'm importing the current features as individual columns. In the old database the features are stored in a giant transaction table that includes all the transactions on the product related to adding, removing, or just quoting a change to the features. Each feature on the product has its own transaction set in the table. If the product never had the feature then there will be no record at all. (Hence the use of left joins) I'm also not pulling every feature type in the table, just the 12. So I can either:

1. Do as you say and use CTE to make a simplified transaction table that contains only the most recent active transactions of only relevant feature sets and then pull from this table by product in my main query.
2. Do as I'm doing now where each feature has its own separate sub query/table of recent transactions within the main query. These tables ONLY contain one feature each. I tried making these sub queries identical but it was coming out more efficient to make them unique because of of the many feature types in the table that I'm not using at all.

I'm not sure which way is better. It sounds like the CTE might be the way to go (as long as I limit it to just the 12 features I want) but it's another thing to teach myself.

Comment: In my opinion, if 8% of the total cost is 11.6911, you might have a ton more problems.

Comment: Can you post the whole query, not just the join portions that are of concerns?  You can probably exclude a bunch of the columns being returned, but at least the full SELECT FROM ... WHERE ... etc.

Comment: It would be good if you posted A) the whole query, B) the tables definitions and C) the execution plan.

Comment: And please explain what you want to accomplish. Three levels of nesting may not be needed.

Comment: If you have multiple nested subqueries, all off of the same base table, can you use CTEs to perform certain rollups (or temp tables)?  Depending on how smart the optimizer is, this may result in just one trip to the base table.

Comment: X-Zero, the way I see it I have two options.

Comment: " Is it better to place the restrictions in the 'join' or in the 'where' clause?" Restrictions MUST be in the join if you are using a left join or you will turn it into an inner join and get different results. For an inner join it shouldn't make a differnce performance wise but it tends to be easier to read if they are inteh where clause.

Comment: what does your indexing look like?

Comment: Hlgem, in the cases where I'm moving it from the 'join' clause to the 'where' clause it is an inner join already.

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the DISTINCT keyword in the subquery; MAX will only return one value per GROUPing columns, so the DISTINCT is redundant.

EDIT: Martin's comment below is correct, but it does raise the possibility of an error in the subquery.  Do you need to group by all three columns or just the first two?  If the former, then I retract my answer; if the latter, you need to clean up your sample :)

Comment: Okay. I removed the Distinct and I'm looking into simplifying the number of columns in my sub-queries. I also could potentially try creating a variable. I've never used variable to create a large static table. It should be possible if not more efficient. As for the query, its 157 lines long and took me a day and a half to write. I'm not going to torture everyone by posting the whole thing and trying to explain it all just yet. I may post a simplified version with examples of the various types of columns.

Comment: @Stuart Just noticed your edit referencing a comment I made. I deleted that comment about the `DISTINCT` being applied to different columns than the `GROUP BY` as I noticed the `WHERE` ensured only one `pt.transaction_cycle` group anyway. I think SQL Server will recognise that the `DISTINCT` is superfluous as well though.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, moving sub-queries into local variables, making them independent queries ahead of queries that use them is a way to improve performance, by forcing those queries to execute only once. Of course this is only possible for certain fixed queries. There is also the issue of worrying about whether or not multiple queries execute as a single atomic unit.

Also, do this **only** when the optimizer doesn't do a good job.

Comment: table varaibles are only more efficient if the result set is small. If the result set is large use temp tables or CTEs